# Launching and killing nodes within a Python node in ROS 2 Foxy

Tags: ros, ros2, roslaunch, rclpy, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm in the process of migrating a ROS Melodic python node into a ROS 2 Foxy python node. This particular node acts as the state machine for our software stack. It receives a message from another part of the system and, depending on the message, will launch a set of nodes described in a launch file.

Previously in ROS melodic we handled this with:

```
    uuid = roslaunch.rlutil.get_or_generate_uuid(None, False)
    roslaunch.configure_logging(uuid)
    LAUNCHED_NODES = roslaunch.parent.ROSLaunchParent(uuid, [full_path])
    LAUNCHED_NODES.start()
```

where `full_path` is the absolute path to a launch file.

Then, when certain conditions are met it will kill these nodes with

```
LAUNCHED_NODES.shutdown()
```

Is there a way to do this in ROS 2 Foxy within a Python node? The nodes that get launched can't block the original node from running. I've played around with launch_service, but I can't get it to stop blocking the original node from continuing to execute.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361087/launching-and-killing-nodes-within-a-python-node-in-ros-2-foxy/) by [siliconlad](https://answers.ros.org/users/59112/siliconlad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-09-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So the way I ended up solving this problem is by running the `ros2 launch` command in a Python subprocess:

```
launch_process = subprocess.Popen(["ros2", "launch", relative_path_to_launch_file], text=True)
```

Then to kill the nodes, I can simply run

```
launch_process.send_signal(SIGINT)
launch_process.wait(timeout=30)
```

When I posted the question, this wasn't working in Foxy. I think it might've been related to these issues [here](https://github.com/ros2/launch/issues/495) and [here](https://github.com/ros2/launch/issues/473). But it works now. It also works with Galactic.

---

Originally posted by [siliconlad](https://answers.ros.org/users/59112/siliconlad/) with karma: 11 on 2021-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0